# How to find the , oracle 11g installed port number

Tags: java, oracle11g

When I try to access my oracle instance using basic connection type. It gives me an error telling "The network adopter could not be able to establish the connection", But I can connect to the same user using TNS connection. What is wrong? As I guess it is not my oracle instance in the default 1521 port number.

Answer (score 31):

If you know SID run TNSPing util

```
tnsping sid
```

and it will show you this info

```
(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Windows7)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))
```

Comment: ok. friend thank you very much for you help. My server is a cloned one from another. I did not changed the net manager settings, that was the problem. I fix it thanks agian.

Comment: This is a bash command rather than a SQL command (took me a few attempts to realise this).

Comment: Running this command gives me this errror `TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name`